Double contact FPC connector
For an LCD,  I got this connector F31L-1A7H1-11015 and in datasheet, it says the connector is double contact point connector, however when I insert the flex PCB of the LCD into this connector, the top side wont contact the pads. I did the continuity check and saw it wont connect. If I insert it upside done, bottom side tracks make contact though. I was wondering If this is a mistake in datasheet?
However under microscope it seems it is double contact but I cannot say for sure.
Anybody can help, do I miss something here?



double contact point does not mean double-sided

Thanks @jsotola. Yes you are right.
I checked the webpage for this series F31L Series now, and it says:
"Contact Location Bottom Contact," but it does not say it in datasheet. and  mentioning Double contact point in datasheet is misleading.

Detail "X" of the technical drawing shows that @jsotola is correct: the contact arm has two bumps on it that touch the same terminal pad of the FFC.
